# Facebook comments social plugin in iPhone iOS Safari Browser has very small fonts and small width

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I'm using the standard Facebook comments social plugin in iPhone iOS Safari Browser but its fonts and width are very small.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="5" mobile="true"></div>
```

Setting the mobile attribute directly didn't help too.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: The standard Facebook Comments widget doesn't seem to automatically adjust to the mobile device.  Am I using the widget incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

I was missing this statement inside my HTML web page:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
```

After adding the statement, the Facebook Comments widget automatically adjusted to the iOS Safari browser.

Comment: Thanks. But what if you can't afford to add this meta tag to your HTML page? Is there a way to force these settings only for the div that contains the FAcebook comments plugin?

Comment: I found that some of the style tips for adjusting the width worked successfully for the Facebook widget, but I couldn't get the similar tips for getting the fonts to be larger to work successfully.


    <style type="text/css">

    * { width:100%!important; }

    </style>